# Running Ethereum Node for pending tx - beginner questions

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py

I have been getting into blockchain development/solidity and started a project where I want to scan all pending tx for specific addresses. I am using python and web3.py and started by using Infura and running the command:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(block_identifier='pending', full_transactions=True)
```

but this way I wasnt able to receive all the pending tx, or filter through them. Now after some research I found that Geth is better to be used for this, but infura doesnt support Geth. So I paid for an ethereum node in the cloud (QuickNode). Now I needed to install Geth on my computer, which I did using Docker. Now here is where I am not too sure what I am doing/ have to do.

After installing Geth I thought that I had to config it and then attach it to the websocket or http provider that I got from QuickNode. I have tried several configurations, for both websocket and http. For some configurations Geth actually starts running and downloading blocks.

So my question is, if I host an ethereum node in the cloud, do I still need to download the blockchain to my computer? Like I said Geth started downloading blocks, but I am not sure if Geth is downloading the new blocks, or if its downloading the whole blockchain. I was hoping that I wouldnt need to store the blockchain (150gb+) on my harddisk if I got an ethereum node running in the cloud.

When Geth is running (using Power shell) I tried to run my script in Python to get pending transactions:

```
    w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(wss_link))
print(w3.geth.txpool.inspect())
```

but whatever I do I keep getting a value error -32601 'method not found'.

Can someone help a noodie out and stear me in the right direction. I might be totally wrong with how I go about it, but I'm trying to learn.

Thanks in advance!